# Different values (also Tuples) in a Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, tuples

I want to create a NSDictionary with multiple key-value pairs and different value-types. My main question is how can i add a simple (2 item)-Tuple and a NSString to a NSDictionary?

Just adding a String or even a Tuple to a NSDictionary is simple.
But to add both is complicated.
I tried this:

```
var myTuple = (longitude: -122.1234, latitude: 55.1234)
var aPersonDictionary: [String:AnyObject] = ["firstname":"Sally", "age":45, "location":myTuple]
```

But this does not work. It gives me the error: `Value of type '(longitude: Double, latitude: Double') does not conform to expected dictionary value type 'AnyObject'`.
I don't understand that because `AnyObject` is everything

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Any` instead of `AnyObject` because `AnyObject` is used for instances of a class type (which a tuple is not), it should be:

```
myTuple = (longitude: -122.1234, latitude: 55.1234)
var aPersonDictionary: [String:Any] = ["firstname":"Sally", "age":45, "location":myTuple]
```

Further explanation:

> - AnyObject can represent an instance of any class type.
> - Any can represent an instance of any type at all, apart from function types.

Comment: Thank you guys for the great help and the detail informations. Now i have a better understanding of that. You both saved my day ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Actually `AnyObject` is not everything. It's representing an instance of any `class` type. Therefore, the thing you would like to have could be `Any` which can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types.

```
var myTuple = (longitude: -122.1234, latitude: 55.1234)
var aPersonDictionary: [String : Any] = ["firstname":"Sally", "age":45, "location":myTuple]
```